# "shipping same as billing" causing address not to be captured

Tags: expresso-store

I have setup my checkout templates exactly like the ones in the example templates, yet bizarely when I check the option "shipping same as billing" the system no longer collects address line 1,2 or three or the city.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Could you clarify where you're expecting to see these stored - member details or order details?  "the system no longer collects address" - I'm assuming you're referring to billing address?

Comment: I don't see them on the next step in the checkout process, nor are they captured into the backend of the store when I look at the details of the order. Thanks

Comment: Can you add your checkout template code?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable "shipping same as billing", then the shipping address will be overwritten by whatever is in the billing address (and shipping address validations won't fire).

Therefore, if you are using that setting, you need to make sure the customer enters a billing address (otherwise it will copy the empty billing address over top of the shipping address).